# NamedQuery an object and compare it to and integer id

Tags: java, jpa, hql, jpql, named-query

i have a situation like this,
would be nice if someone could help me with a solution.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Serializable, Cloneable {
    private int id;
}


public class A extends AbstractEntity{ //Both A and B Entities will store in Table A in Database(in the same table)
    //some code
}

public class B extends A{
    //some fields
}

public class C extends AbstractEntity{  //Data will be Store in Table C in database and there's a column name b_id as integer to hold the id of Entity b
    B b;
}
```

now i have such a Query in my NamedQuery

```
query="SELECT e FROM C e WHERE e.b= :vid"
//int vid;
```

the problem is that JPA throws an exception cause 'b' is a class type var of 'B' and 'vid' is Integer var.

i can't say,

```
query="SELECT e FROM C e WHERE e.b.id= :vid"
```

cause 'b' is extends 'A' and 'A' is extends AbstractEntity, it's what i think, cause i tried it and got some Error ' Parameter value [601] did not match expected type'  //601 is id of an Entity in Table 'A' in Database.

Comment: private member `id` in `AbstractEntity` won't be inherited to class `B`

Comment: i changed it to protected but it give's me 'No default constructor for entity' error @alayor

Answer (score 0):

Add a getter in the mapped superclass to the id field so that your classes could access this field. Making that you'll be able to refer to the field in the query.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Serializable, Cloneable {
    private int id;

    public int getId() { return id; }
}
```

Comment: i have also a getter in my AbstractEntity Class, ichanged it also to protected int id;  still doesn't work @roque-santos